# Symfony 3 set default language to spanish

Tags: php, lang, symfony-3.3

i´m new on symfony and this is a simple question. I need to the spanish as default.

I change the security.yml to

```
framework:
    default_locale: es
    translator: { fallbacks: [es] }
```

But I'm still getting

> Invalid credentials.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A co-worker told me the solution.

Inside the config.yml I needed to change to this

```
parameters:
    locale: es
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it's from which version, but now it's happening on the `config/packages/translation.yaml` file

like this:

```yaml
# config/packages/translation.yaml
framework:
    default_locale: en
```